# Weblogic 12.2.1 managed server access.log not updating

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have developed some JAX-RS web services and deployed the WAR file to a managed server on WebLogic 12.2.1. When I call a web service, either through a client program, or via web browser, I noticed that nothing is getting updated in E:\MLM\MyDomain\servers\MyAppSrv01\logs\access.log. This file stays empty all the time. When the next day comes (at 12.00am), the file will roll over to access.logNNNNN (e.g. access.log00004) and then I can see some of the GET and POST calls of the previous day appearing in access.logNNNNN. The strange thing is that only some of the web service calls appear in access.logNNNNN, even though I make many calls throughout the testing. What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seeing access logs at Run Time due to Buffer Size defined. To reduce I/O Weblogic will write logs to Buffer first and when the limit reaches it will write to access.log file.

Log Buffer Size

The maximum size (in kilobytes) of the buffer that stores HTTP requests. When the buffer reaches this size, the server writes the data to the HTTP log file. Use the LogFileFlushSecs property to determine the frequency with which the server checks the size of the buffer.

You can set this value to 0 for run-time logging.

Comment: Hi, where is the Log Buffer Size and LogFileFlushSecs defined? Is it somewhere in WebLogic console?

Comment: Yes. It's in Weblogic Console. 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_server_logging_http.html

Document is for Weblogic 8.1 but same is applicable for other versions as well.

Comment: There is only a Log File Buffer field with default of 8KB. I changed it to 0. There is no LogFileFlushSecs field though. I am using WebLogic 12.2.1.

Comment: for 12c -> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24403/core/index.html